# Safari Not Opening HTTP Web Pages

Tags: http, safari, apple

Safari will not load any http web pages, I've tried using a private window and clearing cache, cookies and website data, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how I can fix this ?

Comment: It could be a security feature. Does your installed version of Safari open https addresses?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Yes it does.

Comment: That is a known issue with Safari. Two workarounds: 1.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394682/safari-keeps-forcing-https-on-localhost 2. Use another browser. Firefox on Mac does not have that issue, for example.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It's not the same issue, I don't get redirected using https. The webpage just doesn't load at all.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Wait, are you claiming HSTS is a bug?

Comment: @MohamedShereef What happens instead? A timeout? Is there any error message or error code (if so, what is the exact message or code)? Do the sites in question use HSTS? Are you running any Safari extensions that force HTTPS? Can you give an example of a public HTTP website that Safari won't load for you, so we can see how the site behaves?

Comment: @Spliff No errors, just a blank screen that never loads. I'm not sure whether they use HSTS or not but the problem is with every http website, I know this because they work fine using Chrome.

Comment: Could the fact that a header "upgrade-insecure-requests:1" is being sent ?

Comment: Is the header being sent?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but it's also being sent on chrome and there's no issue there.

Comment: You’ll need to provide some more information. There are multiple versions of Safari. You have been asked several questions but you haven’t added that information into your question